# post array of string from angular js controller to asp controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using visual studio 2017 with asp mvc 5.0 and angularJS v1.6.10. I need to send object from angularJS to asp controller via $http service see the following code

```
 public class Patient
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public byte Gender { get; set; }
    public bool IsSmoker { get; set; }
    public string[] Symptoms { get; set; }
    public bool FractionWithTbPatient { get; set; }
    public bool PreviousTbInfection { get; set; }
    public bool Inheritedcysricfibrosis { get; set; }
    public bool Inheritedasthma { get; set; }
    public bool Smokermother { get; set; }
    public bool OrganicDust { get; set; }
    public bool FractionWithanimals { get; set; }
    public bool PreviousSurgery { get; set; }
    public bool Longbonebroken { get; set; }
    public bool Pregnant { get; set; }
    public bool CancerInfection { get; set; }
    public bool LongTimeInBed { get; set; }
    public bool PreviousInfectionWithPulmonaryEmbolism { get; set; }
}
```

and the asp controller method is the following

```
public class ConditionDiagnosisController : Controller{
    [HttpPost]                                                          
    public void GetCaseResult(Patient patient) 
    {                                                                          
        int i = 0;                                                           
        i++;                                    
    }
}
```

and the angularJS controller is the follwoing

```
myApp.controller("mainController",
function ($scope, $http) {

    var patient = new Object();

    patient.Age = 1;
    patient.Gender = 0;
    patient.IsSmoker = false;
    patient.Inheritedasthma = false;
    patient.Symptoms = ['x','y'];
    patient.Pregnant = false;
    patient.FractionWithTbPatient = false;
    patient.PreviousTbInfection = false;
    patient.Inheritedcysricfibrosis = false;
    patient.Inheritedasthma = false;
    patient.Smokermother = false;
    patient.OrganicDust = false;
    patient.FractionWithanimals = false;
    patient.PreviousSurgery = false;
    patient.Longbonebroken = false;
    patient.Pregnant = false;
    patient.CancerInfection = false;
    patient.LongTimeInBed = false;
    patient.PreviousInfectionWithPulmonaryEmbolism = false;
    $scope.go = function () {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/ConditionDiagnosis/GetCaseResult",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $scope.patient,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });
    };
});
```

when I send it I get in the asp method all values of the object correctly else the Symptoms variable which is a string array, I get it null. Any help?

Comment: $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/ConditionDiagnosis/GetCaseResult",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: **JSON.stringify($scope.patient)**,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }); should work. This will convert javascript value to json string before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `data : JSON.stringify($scope.patient)`

Answer (score 0):

in the ASP.NET class, you should assign the Array in the constructor.

the issue will be that you can't assign the array so the best way is to use List

change the type of Symptoms to List and then in the constructor write this code:

```
public Patient(){
  Symptoms = new List();
}
```